# How do I include all fields for my elasticsearch project?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-models

I am trying to implement elasticsearch into my project. Right now it is able to search through the response field in my Response table, but i also want to be able to search through the other fields e.g. Question, Topics, Clients.

When i try to add in "Question" under fields, my site breaks.

documents.py:

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Index, fields
from app.models import Response

@response_index20.doc_type
class ResponseDocument20(DocType):
    class Meta:
        model = Response


        fields = [
            'Response',
            #'Question',
        ]
```

models.py:

```
class Response(models.Model):
    Question = models.ForeignKey(Question, default=436, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, default=13, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Response = models.TextField()
    Client = models.ForeignKey(ClientDetail, default=8, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Planit_location = models.ForeignKey(Planit_location, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Image = models.ForeignKey(Image, default=0, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Date_added = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Response
```

views.py:

```
from app.documents import ResponseDocument20

@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def search_es20(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q')
    if q:#ES
        responses = ResponseDocument20.search().query("wildcard", Response=q)#ES
    else:#ES
        responses = ''#ES

    return render(request, 'app/search_es20.html', {
        'responses': responses,
        'query': q,
    })
```

Comment: Can we see the "breakage" your site experiences when adding `Question`?

Comment: This is the error i get: django_elasticsearch_dsl.exceptions.ModelFieldNotMappedError: Cannot convert model field Question to an Elasticsearch field!

Comment: After making that change, have you run the command to rebuild the index found here: https://github.com/sabricot/django-elasticsearch-dsl? `$ ./manage.py search_index --rebuild`

Comment: Yes and i get the same error stating it cannot be converted to an elasticsearch field